# Google Maps v2 to v3 API wrapper working in Chrome but not in Firefox / IE

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-2

Google announced that after November 19th, a Maps v2 to v3 wrapper would be deployed:

> On November 19, 2013 we will deploy a JavaScript wrapper that attempts
>   to automagically turn remaining v2 maps into v3 maps. Though we expect
>   this wrapper to work for most simple maps, we cannot guarantee that
>   your maps will continue to function. We therefore highly recommend
>   that you migrate to v3 before November 19. The good news is that
>   Google Maps JavaScript API v3 is more robust and feature rich than v2,
>   and we’ve written a guide to assist the migration.

This seems to work with [simple maps](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/examples/marker-simple) in Chrome 31, however it fails with IE9 or Firefox 25.

Has anybody managed to get the wrapper to work in another Browser than Chrome?

**UPDATE:** Ok, the wrapper seems to work now for Chrome, Safari, FF and IE.

Comment: Is there a code question?  If it doesn't work for you, migrate to the v3 API.

Comment: Ok, seems it's a temporary issue - FF at least works with the sample site now.

Comment: Neither Chrome nor FF works: http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~ttel5535/pok_gm/g_simplest.html

Comment: geocodezip, your comment is annoying and not constructive at all. This is real problem all v2 applications are now facing.

Comment: @Tomas Your sample works for me if the language parameter is removed at the end of the api inclusion path: "&amp;hl=cs"

Comment: Everything works *now*! It seems that Google has been debugging the wrapper script in the meantime. Do you still see any problems anywhere?

Comment: @Tomas the only (minor) issue I encountered is that InfoWindows aren't positioned correctly if custom markers are used. In fact most examples from https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/examples/ seem to work.